# Interfaces in functional programming

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

In java and c# we have interfaces, what is the equivalent to that in a language like haskell or what is the concept called in functional programming?

Comment: In the case you are trying to learn Haskell (or any other language) by mapping features from previously known languages, I'd strongly recommend against it. Never try to program in X while thinking in terms of Y -- doing that will only ensure you will find X lacking many things Y has, while missing all the features X has and Y has not, leading to very non-idiomatic code in X.

Comment: @chi i asked because haskell has generics, if it has generics then there must be something similar to interfaces.

Comment: @chi is correct to warn you, though.  If you expect Haskell typeclasses to behave like Java interfaces, just because they both provide polymorphic abstraction, you will be very confused.  Haskell is not object-oriented in any way.

Comment: What Haskell calls generics are pretty much completely unrelated to what Java calls generics.

Comment: There's good answers here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/189047/what-is-the-functional-programming-alternative-to-an-interface

Comment: @chi while there is wisdom in your statement, it's not always the best way to learn.  For me, (and I imagine many people too), assimilating new concepts is vastly easier when I have a context, or reference point to base the new concepts upon.  Learning functional programming concepts by comparing and contrasting them to more mainstream language features can aid in the learning process.

Comment: @jrahhali Sure, comparing and contrasting is indeed a good thing. The issue is found when a programmer's mind is so accustomed to language Y that it can't think of anything else apart what's possible in Y. By contrast, IMO, realizing that Y has features 1,2,3,4 while another language X has 1,4,5,6 is very helpful to achieve a better understanding of both languages.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are things like typeclasses, as the other answers say, but even more than that, there's one pervasive interface: *a function*. Many, many places where an object-oriented program would need some custom interface, a similar functional program can just use a function. eg, `map f xs` in haskell uses `f`, where an object-oriented program might use a Strategy or whatever to accomplish the same task.

Comment: Some mention of the "expression problem" may be in order.

Comment: This answer needs more emphasis.  Things you would solve with an interface in java are usually best solved with functions in haskell.  Type classes are something very different, and attempting to use them like interfaces will lead you to pain.

Answer (score 7):

Haskell [typeclasses](https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/classes.html) fulfill some of the same roles as interfaces in object oriented languages.

Answer (score 2):

The function signature (the input and output types of your function) along with 2:nd order functions (functions that can be put in variables) take the role that an Interface has in object oriented languages. As long as the function signature matches the expected type, you can substitute one function for another.

For instance, assume a function `f` that takes two arguments: An integer `a` and a function `g`, where the function argument `g` should in turn be a function that takes an `int` and returns a `str`:

For example (in pseudocode for all that are curious about functional programming):

```
fun f(a: int, g:int->str) -> int
```

Just by declaring the parameter `g`, you have now created an interface: You can only pass a function for the parameter `g` that matches the signature of `g`, but as long as you match that signature, you can pass any function.

Answer (score -2):

**data** and **newtype** in Haskell are approximately equal to **class** in Java.

**class** in Haskell is approximately equal to **interface** in Java.